# Система частиц Unity. Разное отображение в сцене и игре

Tags: unity3d

День добрый.

Создавал я тут эффект залпа стрел в Unity. С анимацией, всё по красоте. Работало как надо (вроде бы), но тут я решил детализировать стрелы. Нарисовал спрайт лист побольше (576х96).

[image: спрайт лист побольше]

В самом редакторе сцены было всё отлично, но тут я запустил игру(в редакторе) и увидел то, от чего чуть не расплакался. Все стрелы сжаты.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Еще больше я удивился, когда поставил игру на паузу и заглянул в окно сцены. Здесь всё рисует, можно сказать, идеально.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Потом заглянул я в сам материал частиц, и вот что увидел в предпросмотре:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

НО, такая дичь творится, только когда я выставляю случайное значения поворота стрел на протяжении их полета:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если данный модуль выключить, то всё отрисовывается корректно. Я, пока что, так и сделал, ведь мне нужна рабочая версия программы. Но хотелось бы оставить колебания стрел, да еще и отрисовку нормальную а не сжатую(

Было бы очевидно, что это я набокопорил с повотором, но изображения в разных окнах разные... К такому меня жизнь не готовила.

Может знает кто, в чем прикол? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Предположение, настройки камеры (Game окна) - перспектива. Настройки Scene - ортогональны?

Comment: Егор Башинский, камера в ортогональной проекции.

Comment: У текстуры со стрелами поиграйся с фильтрацией(билинейная, ит.д). Убери mipmaps. Поиграйся с анизотропной фильтрацией, антиалисингом. Еще идея, если проблема при повороте, возможно надо настройки renderer у партикла подергать, в плане отображения(billboard ит.п.). Если бы скинул пример с этими стрелами, можно было бы посмотреть подробнее.

Comment: Попробуйте сделать спрайтшит квадратной изначально, и стрелы в соотвествующем формате разложите, это как вариант.

Comment: Пока делал пример, разобрался. Видимо, поворот был выставлен и по осям X/Y, хотя я его ставил в 0. Странно. В общем, убрав галочку разделения векторов скорости по осям, все стало нормально. Хотя феномен разного отображения в разных окнах это не объясняет....